# Tkinter: function starts when running tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have searched for similar questions but I can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. I have this code for a very simple gui. The code in googl1 is a scraper that extracts information from google. But I have this problem where when I run the code for the gui, the scraper starts before the gui is shown.
Could someone explain why this is?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from functools import partial

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

import google1


#----Functions----------------------------------------------------------------

def fileDialog(): 
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("excel workbook","*.xlsx"),("all files","*.*")))        
    label = ttk.Label(labelFrame, text = "")
    label.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
    label.configure(text = filename)
    print(filename)
    
def start_program(filename):
    if filename:
        print("this is the filename", filename)
        google1.start_program
    else:
        messagebox(title="No file detected", message="Please select file first")

#----Tkinter-setup------------------------------------------------------------

root = tk.Tk()

#initial placeholder for gui
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#a frame within the canvas
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff')
frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)


labelFrame = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text = "Select File")
labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)

labelFrame_start = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text = "Start Program")
labelFrame_start.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx = 20, pady = 20)

button = tk.Button(labelFrame, text = "Browse Files", command = fileDialog)
button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

button = tk.Button(labelFrame_start, text = "Click to start program", command = lambda: start_program(filename))
button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

edit: this (the scraper starting before seeing the gui) also happens when I comment out the google1.start_program, but still have the import. When I also comment out the import, that is when i do get the gui first.

Comment: My guess is that  `start_program` function of `google1` module is probably getting executed because it is getting called in google1.py file somewhere. To get a better understanding we need to see your `google1` file.

Comment: Agree with @Saad. Does your google1.py file have any functions? Does it have a `if __name__ == '__main__:' in it?

Comment: It HAS to be something in `google1`, as the code you posted is incapable of starting the process - `google1.start_program` just references the function, you'd need `()` after that to actually call it.